# What word contains the most unique letters?

Tags: word-games, alphabet

I'm assuming there isn't a word that contains every letter in the alphabet, so which word contains the most?

Examples:

antidisestablishmentarianism - 12 `[antidseblhmr]`
psychotherapy - 10 `[psychotera]`
handcraftsmanship - 12 `[handcrftsmip]`

Comment: Actually, this is *not* a dupe of ["What is the longest word in the English language without a repeated letter?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/834/), as this question here expressly allows letters to be repeated. Check out OP's examples.

Comment: EXTINCTIONSPECTROPHOTOPOLERISCOPEOCCULOGRAVOGYROKYNETOMETER

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Among words in a certain [word list](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/) I found:

```
(18, 'llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch')
```

It has ten words with 16, including:

```
(16, 'superacknowledgement')
(16, 'pseudolamellibranchiate')
(16, 'pneumoventriculography')
(16, 'phenylthiocarbamides')
(16, 'hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia')
(16, 'formaldehydesulphoxylic')
(16, 'blepharoconjunctivitis')
```

There are several dozen with 15, including:

```
(15, 'undiscoverability')
(15, 'uncopyrightable')
(15, 'supermagnificently')
(15, 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious')
(15, 'submetaphorically')
(15, 'spondylotherapeutics')
(15, 'semiautobiographical')
(15, 'pterygomandibular')
(15, 'pseudoromantically')
(15, 'overdiscriminatingly')
(15, 'neuropharmacologists')
(15, 'hyperconstitutionalism')
(15, 'honorificabilitudinities')
(15, 'gumpoldskirchner')
(15, 'formaldehydesulphoxylate')
(15, 'encephalomyocarditis')
(15, 'dermatoglyphics')
```

and several hundred with 14 (including a few 14-letter words like 'pseudomythical', 'hydropneumatic' and 'ambidextrously').

In case anyone cares, this was done with Python, something like:

```
F = open('words.list').readlines()
for i in range(len(F)):
    w = F[i].strip().lower()
    F[i] = (len(set(w)), w)
F = sorted(F, reverse=True)
for i in range(len(F)): print F[i]
```

A better word list (one that includes [*subdermatoglyphic*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/834/what-is-the-longest-word-in-the-english-language-without-a-repeated-letter/849#849), for instance!) may give longer words. And you didn't ask about two words, but just for reference: [this](http://digitalcommons.butler.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2035&context=wordways) says "Ralph Beaman proposes **formaldehydesulphoxylic ventriloquizing** as a two-word combination having 22 different letters which should be difficult to beat"; I haven't checked this.

Comment: Given as how this isn't a programming site, it might be worth mentioning that you've used python here.

Comment: @dmckee: Ok, done. Although, "given as how this isn't a programming site", perhaps I should have removed the code altogether!

Comment: I like that you've displayed your python code.

Comment: `perl -le'for(@ARGV){my %s;@s{split//,lc}=();print$n=()=keys%s}'` `superstition Subdermatoglyphic Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch` produces `9 17 18` — and involves significantly less monkeywork and prestidigitation.

Comment: @tchrist: I don't understand your comment? Are you comparing code? The code wasn't the point of the answer. [In any case, if all one wanted was to find lengths of words, then in Python something like `python -c "print [len(w)-1 for w in open('/usr/share/dict/words').readlines()]"` would do, but it would not give sorted output in (length, word) format. To do the full thing also, I don't doubt that in Perl it can be done with fewer lines and less readability; I only added the code in the spirit of "show your work". :-)]

Comment: You can't use `llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch` here because it's not an English word - it's Welsh. You've probably counted `c` and `h` as two separate letters where `ch` is a *single* letter in the welsh alphabet. Similarly Welsh has `l` and `ll` as two different letters with two different sounds and both appear in `Llanfairpwll...`

Comment: @Gareth: That's informative, thanks. Of course, whether something is an English word is loosely defined, and appearance in a word list is as good a metric as I can think of -- leave the decision to the word list, essentially. (The *place* is in Wales, but does that make it a Welsh word? Is "London" an English word? How about "Boston" or "Tokyo"?) BTW if we count according to Welsh letters (counting 'ch' as 1) it appears that we'll also have to count 'll' as 1, so we're back to 18 as it contains both 'll' and 'l'. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I'd argue that `LlanfairPG` does count as a Welsh word since it actually has a (stupid and convoluted) meaning in Welsh. And yes, I noticed as I was writing my comment that the letter count is the same because of the `ll` and `l` counter-balancing the `ch` :-).

Answer (score 12):

[Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch) clocks in at 18 distinct characters, but arguably a near-infinite number of 25-character answers exist, since organic chemistry nomenclature allows one to build valid hypothetical compound names of essentially arbitrary length, and the full alphabet less only J appears on the periodic table (though this does require one to refer to rutherfordium by its old placeholder name unnilquadium or arrogate a placeholder name for a transuranic element with an atomic number ending in 4 that hasn't been named yet, so it may only get us to 24 characters).

Answer (score 4):

*Uncopyrightable* is supposedly the longest word in the English language with no repeated letters, which makes it a logical starting point.  That sets the bar at 15 unique letters.

Comment: The funny part is that it does not appear in ShreevatsaR's list from `/usr/share/dict/words`.

Comment: make it plural, and that's 16 unique letters. Also, less common are: dermatoglyphics and misconjugatedly [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_word_in_English#Words_with_certain_characteristics_of_notable_length)

Answer (score 3):

*Subdermatoglyphic* = 17 (longest one seen so far).